# couchbase xdcr with compression

Tags: couchbase, database-replication

I understand that for xdcr couchbase is using ports 8091 and 8092. Also, under v2.5, there is no encryption.

With reference to http://tech.3scale.net/2012/07/25/fun-with-redis-replication/
Can I use the same ssh -c on 8091 and 8092 such that couchbase xdcr can be done with compression?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of XDCR different ports are used. This table has the full list:

http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-install/#xdcr

In 2.5 there is encryption for XDCR:

http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-release-notes/#xdcr-data-encryption-feature

If you do use XDCR encryption, you will not be able to use the ssh port forwarding to get compression.

Comment: How to use ssh port compression if I do not use xdcr compression? Any tutorials?